# Grayscale in CSS + Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors, grayscale

Can someone help me, I was creating my site in html and wanted to make the images initially be in the "grayscale" color scheme and when clicking were colored, I used (filter: grayscale(1);) in css and I would like to know how do I click the image back to color.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on @Sina Kadkhodaei its answer, I would do the onclick this way. More readable imo.

```js
function removeClass(element) {
    element.classList.remove("filter");
}
```

```css
.filter {
    filter: grayscale(1);
}
```

```html
<img class="filter" onclick="removeClass(this)" src="https://downloadly.ir/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Acronis-True-Image.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want colorize when mouse pressed, use `:active` in css:

```css
#sample{
  filter: grayscale(1);
}

#sample:active{
  filter: grayscale(0);
}
```

```html
<img id="sample" src="https://downloadly.ir/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Acronis-True-Image.png">
```

**Or**

If you want colorize when mouse clicked use `onclick` and `style.filter` in JS:

```js
let imgs=document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for(let i=0;i<imgs.length;i++)
imgs[i].onclick=function(){this.style.filter="grayscale(0)";};
```

```css
#sample{
filter: grayscale(1);
}
```

```html
<img id="sample" src="https://downloadly.ir/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Acronis-True-Image.png">
```